# Issue in Query to find users who have not commented on any posts for last xx days

Tags: mysql, database, days

I have been working on **mysql** query to find users who have not posted any comments against any posts in last 10 days.
I have written something like this below. But could not find expected results.

I have three tables Users, Posts, Comments.

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON u.userID = p.postID
LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON p.postID = c.postID 
group by p.p.postID 
having  (max(t.addedDate) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY));
```

this query still returning me users who have posted comments in last 10 days. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. If anyone can help me here?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. You have alias `t` in the `having` clause, bot no such table in the `from` clause. Also, join condition `u.userID = p.postID`  seems suspicious to me.

Comment: Nothing is suspicious here. I just had given different alias before and changed that to make it relevant here and forgot to update in having clause. 
Here's the updated version:


SELECT * FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON u.userID = p.userID LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON p.postID = c.postID group by p.p.postID having (max(c.addedDate) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY));

Comment: The logic here is completely wrong. First of all, you don't need the `users - posts` relationship. You should have and use a `users - comments` relationship. Second, try approaching your problem using SQL `not exists` or `not in` operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exists logic would seem to be the most literal translation of your requirement:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM posts p
                  INNER JOIN comments c ON p.postID = c.postID
                  WHERE p.userID = u.userID AND
                        c.addedDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But what can be wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:
You want to find users who have not posted **any comments against any posts** in the last 10 days. Joining `users` to `posts` and then `comments` will give you users who **created a post which has some comments**. Any further filtering will be applied to that wrong subset.

Here is a guess on how to solve it, assuming your `comments` table does have a `userId` field. Otherwise, please add your schema to the question.

```
select * 
from users u
where u.id not in (
    select c.userID 
    from comments c 
    where c.addedDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
)
```